# Calculating max value over time

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

So I have three tables on an MS SQL Server:

- Reserves (ReserveID, ProjectID, TypeID, DateCreated, Current (binary), Amount)
- Payments (PaymentID, ProjectID, TypeID, DateCreated, Status, Amount)
- Links (LinkID, ReserveID, PaymentID)

Type splits payments/reserve around things like Building Materials, Fixtures, labour costs, professional services etc

So when a project starts a series of reserves will be set up based on the anticipated costs.

It is possible that you initially guestimate that materials are going to cost $5,000 but then after making some enquiries you realise its going to be more like $10,000 in which case a new reserve for $10,000 is set and the "current" status in the table of the original item is set to 0

When an invoice comes in and is paid it goes into Payment table and a link between the reserve and payment is entered into the third table. When it is presented to the user in the front end the payment is deducted from the reserve but in the backend the reserve table is untouched. Eg if there is a reserve of $10,000 for Materials and an invoice for $2,500 of materials is paid then the backend will still have a 10k reserve and 2.5k payment but the front end will display 7.5k reserve, 2.5k payment and 10k total.

If a payment exceeds the reserve for a type then the front end will show a reserve of 0, 12k payment and 12k total. (The reserves for any other types will remain untouched - ie if material go 5k over budget then the labour reserve isnt reduced).

If the reserve is  altered after a payment (which results in a new row in the Reserve table) then the front end stops deducting the prior payments from it. So in the previous example the the front end was displaying 7.5k reserve, 2.5k payment and 10k total. If the user then changes the reserve to 10k then the front end will show 10k reserve, 2.5k payment and 12.5k payment.

Is a poor way of doing things but I cannot change the front end.

So what I need to do is calculate what the Maximum total was for each project at any point in time. In the perfect world this would be the current position but it is possible that things were overestimated in the past and then the reserve reduced when it was discovered something could be repaired rather than replaced etc.

I am at a loss as how to do this at all, let alone in an efficient way to run over a fairly large dataset.

Many thanks for your help.

**Sample Data**

*Reserve*

```
ReserveID ProjectID TypeID  DateCreated Current Amount

23  64  4   03/01/2020  0   5,000.00 
24  65  3   03/01/2020  1   1,000.00 
25  64  4   05/01/2020  1   10,000.00 
26  64  1   08/01/2020  1   500.00 
27  66  1   09/01/2020  1   750.00 
28  64  3   10/01/2020  1   250.00 
29  68  3   10/01/2020  0   20,000.00 
30  68  3   11/01/2020  1   5,000
```

*Payment*

```
PaymentID   ProjectID   TypeID  DateCreated Status  Amount

87  64  4   08/01/2020  Declined    10,000.00 
88  64  8   09/01/2020  Approved    1,000.00 
89  71  2   10/01/2020  Approved    5,000.00 
90  66  1   12/01/2020  Approved    700.00
```

*Links*

```
LinksID ReserveID   PaymentID

21  25  87
22  25  88
23  27  90
```

*Desired Output*

```
ProjectID   MaxPotentialCost

64   11,750.00 
65   1,000.00 
66   750.00 
68   20,000.00 
71   5,000.00
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would really help.

Comment: Sorry, what was is a "database tag"?

Comment: . . It specifies what database you are using . . . mysql, postgresql, sql-server, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, now added

Comment: And thanks to whoever it is that keeps correcting my layout :)

Comment: Isn't that just the greatest of `MAX(reserve)` and `SUM(approved payments)`?  The total is only ever equal to the current reserve or the total payments to date (if they exceed the reserve)?  So, the highest total to date is either the highest reserve or the total of all payments, just take whichever is higher?

Comment: No its not unfortunately...

Take the example of a $10,000 reserve, the reserve then drops to $5,000 and then a $20,000 payment is added... the answer would need to be $25,000 because the reserve had dropped by the time the payment was added and so the two didnt co-exist. If instead the reserve had originally been $30,000 then the answer would have been $30,000

Comment: Your question contradicts your comment. In your question you say that if the payments are 12k and exceed the reserve, the values are: reserve = 0, payments = 12k, total = 12k.  Please update/correct the question, and provide concrete examples that demonstrate the actual behaviours you need us to account for.

Comment: Sorry, it wasnt a clear example as the reserve/payments are looked at at type level so the example in the comment was supposed to be where the payment was for a different type and therefore doesnt impact the reserve. I have tried to make it clearer in the main description too on the interaction between payment and reserve

Comment: What's the relevance of the link table?  I can already associate a payment to a reserve via the ProjectID,TypeID.  If I used the Links table instead, wouldn't it be possible for a payment to become associated toa deprecated (Current=0) row in the Reserves?

Comment: something like `MAX([Value]) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY [ProjectId]) AS max` or  `SUM` with window function. Can you create a fiddle from this? By the way for `ProjectId=64` shouldn't it be 15,750?

Comment: @MatBailie I did try to explain in the main question having  worked it out myself... the link is used for eroding the current reserve. So payments reduce the reserve to which they are linked but not ones they are not linked to even if its for the same type and project. Once a new reserve is set then previous payments don't reduce it but future payments will until a new reserve is set again. The setting of a new reserve causes a new line to be entered and the old reserve's "Current" status to be set to 0.  IE the reserve set is the users estimate of future costs not the total cost.

Comment: @lukaszberwid  Its a reserve of 10,75 from rows 25, 26 & 28 and a payment of 1k under payment 87. Row 23 was superceeded by row 25 so doesnt count and the payment was made against a type without a reserve and so doesnt decrease it.

Comment: @DanLondon - Okay, I think I understand the data now.  In terms of the meaning of the value you're exposing...  If a reserve is set to $2k, then $3k is spent, then the reserve is revised to $1k, what should the "total" be?  It feels like you're measuring "exposure", which means that the "total" should be $4k?

Comment: @MatBailie the max total would be $4k as you say - 3k from the spend and 1k for the new reserve set after the payments made. My biggest headache is the time element as whilst I can probably workout the max for a single project/type where I lost is the max for the whole project as this may not be the sum of the maxes for a single project/type combination as the reserves and payments move independently.

Comment: I have a method, I just need to type it, aqfter I eat dinner.  *(Work out the ChangeInExposure on each day at a ProjectType level.  You can then use a cumulative SUM() on those delta values to get back TotalExposure, and you can do that over as many dffernt types as you like.)*

Comment: I had considered doing a daily calc (not that I was sure how to do it) and then a max but was wondering the efficiency of this as its a fairly large dataset that it needs to be run over (though any one project typically has under 15 reserves/movements and under 5 or so payments with a duration of 2 years) but only for a defined list of ProjectIDs (a big number out of a very much bigger number). Your help is much appreciated @MatBailie

Comment: @DanLondon From what you've said, you have no choice but to do it daily.  If a Reserve is revised down then the Exposure can also go down, while at the same time the exposure might go up on a different TypeID.  As far as I can tell, the only way to resolve that is to find the exposure on a daily basis, and then find the max.

Comment: it may be, the db already has a view that creates the current exposure (ie all payments + any outstanding reserves factoring in erosion) and that view takes 1hr20 to run for the projects I am interested in - though Im told its quicker to put the view into a temp table and then run the wider query. To find max exposure is clearly more complicated hence the concern on time it'll take to execute.

Comment: Did any of this help? (Politeness would dictate at least Some feedback on an answer given to your question.)

Answer (score 0):

While it's not completely clear to me what you want *(the example doesn't feel very robust or complete)* I can give you a working example that at least *(hopefully)* covers the methodology you seem to want.

*(I'm going to make up my own data to be more demonstrative of what I mean...)*

```
ProjectID  TypeID  EffectiveDate  Reserve

64         4       01/01/2020      1,000
64         4       07/01/2020      5,000
64         4       11/01/2020      1,000

64         5       12/01/2020      1,000


ProjectID  TypeID  EffectiveDate  Payment

64         4       03/01/2020      1,000
64         4       05/01/2020      1,000
64         4       09/01/2020      2,000

64         5       10/01/2020      3,000
```

First thing would seem to be getting everything in a single time series data-set rather than two.  Then have a running total of payments to date, rather than the individual amounts.  That makes is easier to calulate the Exposure (The "total" you refer to), for each `(ProjectId,TypeID)`.

```
PID,TID   EffectiveDate   Reserve   Payment   NewSpent   OldSpent   Exposure

64,4      01/01/2020        1,000         0         0         0     1,000   -- Reserve Added
64,4      03/01/2020        1,000     1,000     1,000         0     1,000   -- Payment Made, so newSpent increases
64,4      05/01/2020        1,000     1,000     2,000         0     2,000   -- Payment Made, so newSpent increases
64,4      07/01/2020        5,000         0         0     2,000     7,000   -- Reserve Revised, newSpent is added to OldSpent and then resets to zero 
64,4      09/01/2020        5,000     2,000     2,000     2,000     7,000   -- Payment Made, so newSpent increases
64,4      11/01/2020        1,000         0         0     4,000     5,000   -- Reserve Revised, newSpent is added to OldSpent and then resets to zero 

64,5      10/01/2020            0     3,000     3,000         0     3,000   -- Payment Made, so newSpent increases
64,5      12/01/2020        1,000         0         0     3,000     4,000   -- Reserve Revised, newSpent is added to OldSpent and then resets to zero
```

Example SQL:

```
WITH
  combined AS
(
  SELECT
    payments.ProjectID,
    payments.TypeID,
    links.ReserveID,
    payments.DateCreated,
    COALESCE(reserve.Amount, 0)   AS reserve,
    payments.Amount               AS spent
  FROM
    payments
  LEFT JOIN
    links
      ON payments.PaymentID = links.PaymentID
  LEFT JOIN
    reserve
      ON reserve.ReserveID  = links.ReserveID        
  WHERE
    payments.status = 'Approved'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    reserve.ProjectID,
    reserve.TypeID,
    reserve.ReserveID,
    reserve.Amount,
    0
  FROM
    reserve
)
,
  runningTotal AS
(
  SELECT
    ProjectID,
    TypeID,
    DateCreated,
    reserve,
    SUM(spent)
      OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID, TypeID, ReserveID
                ORDER BY DateCreated
           )
             AS spentReserve,
    SUM(spent)
      OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID, TypeID
                ORDER BY DateCreated
           )
             AS spentProjectType
  FROM
    combined
)
,
  exposure AS
(
  SELECT
    ProjectID,
    TypeID,
    DateCreated,
    reserve,
    spentReserve                      AS spentNew,
    spentProjectType - spentReserve   AS spentOld,
    CASE WHEN
      spentReserve > reserve  -- If new spending exceeds the current reserve
    THEN                      -- The the exposure equals total spending to date
      spentProjectType        -- Otherwise it's the old spent value, plus the reserve
    ELSE
      spentProjectType - spentReserve + reserve
    END
                                      AS exposure
  FROM
    runningTotal
)
```

At this point I'd then collapse it all down to how much the "Exposure" has changed by, as that will make interleaving multiple Types simpler.

```
PID,TID   EffectiveDate   Exposure   Delta

64,4      01/01/2020      1,000      1,000   -- Reserve Added
64,4      03/01/2020      1,000          0   -- Payment Made
64,4      05/01/2020      2,000      1,000   -- Payment Made
64,4      07/01/2020      7,000      5,000   -- Reserve Revised
64,4      09/01/2020      7,000          0   -- Payment Made
64,4      11/01/2020      5,000     -2,000   -- Reserve Revised

64,5      10/01/2020      3,000      3,000   -- Payment Made
64,5      12/01/2020      4,000      1,000   -- Reserve Revised
```

Example SQL:

```
,
  deltaExposure AS
(
  SELECT
    exposure.*,
    exposure.exposure
    -
    LAG(exposure.exposure, 0)
      OVER (PARTITION BY exposure.ProjectID, exposure.TypeID
                ORDER BY exposure.DateCreated
           )
             AS deltaExposure
  FROM
    exposure
)
```

Then the multiple types can then be interleaved in time order and the DeltaExposure values added up across the whole project...

```
PID,TID   EffectiveDate   Delta   ProjectExposure

64,4      01/01/2020      1,000      1,000   -- Reserve Added
64,4      03/01/2020          0      1,000   -- Payment Made
64,4      05/01/2020      1,000      2,000   -- Payment Made
64,4      07/01/2020      5,000      7,000   -- Reserve Revised
64,4      09/01/2020          0      7,000   -- Payment Made
64,5      10/01/2020      3,000     10,000   -- Payment Made
64,4      11/01/2020     -2,000      8,000   -- Reserve Revised
64,5      12/01/2020      1,000      9,000   -- Reserve Revised
```

Example SQL:

```
,
  projectExposure AS
(
  SELECT
    deltaExposure.*,
    SUM(deltaExposure.exposure)
      OVER (PARTITION BY deltaExposure.ProjectID
                ORDER BY deltaExposure.DateCreated
           )
             AS projectExposure
  FROM
    deltaExposure
)
SELECT
  ProjectID,
  MAX(ProjectExposure)   AS MaxProjectExposure
FROM
  projectExposure
GROUP BY
  ProjectID
```

***Example to show that the day by day calculation is needed:***

Imagine a project consisting of two parts Exp1 and Exp2.  After the exposures are calculated on each event date (each payment or reserve revision), we get the following "DeltaExposure" values.

```
Date   01  02  03  04  05
Exp1   +2  +2  +2  +2       -- Reserve set to 2, then payments of 4, 2 and 2
Exp2   +6          -4  +1   -- Reserve set to 6, later revised to 2, then a payment of 3

TOTAL   8  10  12  10  11
```

The peak exposure is on the date of the 2nd payment on Exp1.  The middle payment of three; there's no way to know which payment Dates from Exp1 are candidates for peak exposure without accounting for all the other time series...

Comment: Made a few typo corrections and added a little bit of elaboration.  I'd comment it all a bit more, but I have to go pack for a business trip.  I hope it makes enough sense to help you.

Comment: In terms of performance, it may be that running the first query *(called `combined` in the CTEs)* in to a temp tabel ***with useful indexes for later stages*** may be beneficial.